# Null pointer issue in android action bar setLogo

Tags: android

I am trying to study about actionbar.

Below is the code written.

```
package com.example.jeyshree.actbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab=getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setLogo(R.drawable.test);
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

}

I face the below issue

```
Process: com.example.jeyshree.actbar, PID: 13896
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jeyshree.actbar/com.example.jeyshree.actbar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setLogo(int)' on a null object reference
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setLogo(int)' on a null object reference
```

I have added an image named test.png in drawable folder.

please let me know where i am going wrong[image]

[androidmanifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3WfP.png)
[style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnGIH.png)

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I am using Apptheme(images attched in now in attcahments section.plz check)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of NPE is this LOC, please remove it

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionbar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Xml Code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

java code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.icon);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

style xml:

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

<item name="android:icon">@drawable/logo</item>
<item name="logo">@drawable/logo</item>
<item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>
```

it helps you